# JQuery Mobile Listview Malfunction: not working with Database in Phonegap Android

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an android project where I am fetching some sqlite database value and showing them in a listview. Here is my code of that part:

```
var getDB = document.getElementById("mainDB");
tx.executeSql("SELECT id,title,state FROM recipe WHERE cat_id="+local_Category, [], function(tx,res){
    var i = 0;
    var c=null;
    c="<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Search foods...' data-inset='true'>";
    while(i<res.rows.length){
      c=c+"<li><a href='foodDescription.html'>"+res.rows.item(i).title+"<b style='color: cyan'>"+res.rows.item(i).state+"</b></a></li>";
      i++;
    }

    c=c+"</ul>";
    getDB.innerHTML=c;
```

But when I get to this page from the index page, the content part with the listview is not showing up. It shows blank. When I press the back button, it's not getting me back to the index.html but another one. There it shows the same header "Home" as the index page should show. But in the content area, the values fetched from the database is showing up in an unordered list, not in the listview. Then if I press the back button again, it closes the app. I have to relaunch it again to get to index page.

I am not sure if I am showing all the necessary parts of my code to understand the situation. If anything else is needed to give here, please let me know that. I am new to phonegap and JQuery Mobile. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: After `getDB.innerHTML` add the following `$("[data-role=listview]").listview().listview("refresh");`.